# Writing a java application within a Spring-Hibernate web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a java web application using JSF, Spring and Hibernate frameworks. I want to write a batch program (with `main()` method) processing some data in the related database and I want to use some Spring Beans from the web application! Can anybody provide me with a proper guidance on how to access those beans from the main method without using a web request.

Answer (score 1):

```
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("xml1", "xml2");
  context.getBean("Somebean");
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to "share" the actual runtime beans with a stand alone application, but you can re-create the same beans by creating an application context using the same xml files. If you actually want to re-use the runtime bean instances, you would have to "spawn" your application as a part of the web application, e.g. as a background thread, a scheduled Job, or just a management operation that can be triggered either by requesting a certain URL, or maybe via JMX.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer these two links.

1.) [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)

2.) [Example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html)